# Where can I access the tables under Master table in SQL Server 2012 Express?

Tags: sql-server-2012-express

I did a

```
select * from mytablename
```

and it is clearly there. But under the GUI Microsoft took out the tables link?

Answer (score 1):

The `master` database can be seen under the `System Databases` in Object Explorer:

[image]

But why are you putting your tables into the `master` database!??!? That's not something you should be doing ....

Comment: Hey thanks for your screenshot. But is your version sql express 2012? Because in my 2005,2008 express no problems...only 2012 express I cannot see the tables folder.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I guess Microsoft has removed it in SQL Express 2012 or something like that as I too cannot see the 'Tables' link under the master database.